# How do you initialize an empty bytes.Buffer of size N in Go?

Tags: go

What is the easiest method to create an empty buffer of size `n` in Go using [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer)?

Comment: `NewBuffer(make([]byte,0,N))`?

Comment: Do as @leafbebop describes. This is [mentioned in the NewBuffer documentation](https://godoc.org/bytes#NewBuffer): _It can also be used to size the internal buffer for writing. To do that, buf should have the desired capacity but a length of zero._

Answer (score 24):

Adding some additional info here. The quick way to create a new buffer is briefly mentioned at the end of the doc string:

```
b := new(bytes.Buffer)
```

or

```
b := &bytes.Buffer{}
```

The `Buffer` struct define includes a 64 byte internal `bootstrap` field that is initially used for small allocations. Once the default size is exceeded, a byte slice `Buffer.buf` is created and internally maintained.

As @leafbebop suggested we can pre-initalize the `buf` field of the `Buffer` struct using a new slice.

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte,0,N))
```

I also found another option to use the `Grow()` method:

```
b := new(bytes.Buffer)
b.Grow(n)
```

Also it's interesting to point out that the internal `buf` slice will grow at a rate of `cap(buf)*2 + n`. This means that if you've written 1MB into a buffer and then add 1 byte, your `cap()` will increase to [2097153](https://play.golang.org/p/xEDueMr41tR) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The `bytes.buffer` zero value is usable as is, so you can skip the initialization step. Code snippet from [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer).

```
var b bytes.Buffer // A Buffer needs no initialization.
b.Write([]byte("Hello "))
```